# Why is this element in my code not hiding? No JS only CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a dice roll game project for school, using only HTML and CSS without any JS. I'm having an issue with hiding a div element when clicking on a anchor element. I am trying to hide dice1 div when I click on the dice2 button but it isn't doing that.

[screenshot after clicking roll button 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWqgq.png)

I've double checked the ids on the html code and css code to make sure it was matching and it looked correct.

```css
#dice2:target~#dice1 {
  display: none;
}

#dice2:target~#dice2-link {
  display: none;
}

#dice2:target~#dice1-link {
  display: none;
}

#dice2:target~#dice3-link,
#dice2:target {
  display: block;
}

#dice2:target {
  animation: roll2 5s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dice1" id="dice1">
    <div class="face face1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dice2" id="dice2">
    <div class="face face1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#dice1" id="dice1-link">Roll Dice 1</a>
  <a href="#dice2" id="dice2-link">Roll Dice 2</a>
  <a href="#dice3" id="dice3-link">Roll Dice 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't try to use Markdown in code; it just screws up the code. Instead, add a comment to the lines of code we should be interested in, or reduce your code to just those lines necessary to reproduce the issue, rather than the whole app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "previous sibling" selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think so. I will look into it more, thanks!